# The [polyglot-programming] tag as an example for a Badge proposal

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, badges, badge-request

Currently, there are 9 questions under [[polyglot-programming]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/polyglot-programming). IMHO, the use of this tag is not justified for most of theses questions. For instance, one question relates to both C# and F#, and has these two tags. No need for an additional tag.

I believe there are many other examples of such tags that add entropy to the site instead of decreasing it.

AFAIK, if these questions are edited to remove this tag, and no other question is tagged under it, it will be automatically removed from the system after 24 hours.

Why not reward the user who untags the last question under an obscure tag, thus causing it to be removed?

Of course there must be some criteria for a tag to be considered obscure, let's say it must have been created at least `x` months ago, and must not have more than `y` questions in total.

I thought of some names for such a badge, "Garbage Collector" may be too obvious, "Vulture" may be somewhat disgusting. :-)

That's it, just a discussion to kill some time :-)

Comment: What keeps people from removing *valid* low-occurrence tags just to earn badges?

Comment: @CodyGray, good point. Well, users below 2k rep must have their edits reviewed. And if you think that unscrupulous badge-hunters may exploit this, then you can take countermeasures, such as increasing the rep threshold for an edit that removes the tag from the last question...

Comment: That doesn't really fix the problem, it just assumes we can trust high-rep users not to game the badge system. Which I guess is reasonable, but kind of misses the whole point. The people who have the necessary intrinsic motivation to do this don't care about gaining badges for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you ask me, this isn't necessary, or a good idea.

People shouldn't have any motivation to secretly destroy valid low use tags. Any tag destruction should be brought to meta, discussed, and, if it's agreed on, then many people work together to get it done quickly and efficiently.

While people under 2k have their edits reviewed, that's no guarantee. The review system is good at catching individual bad edits, but (and I know this from experience), it takes a large, meta-coordinated army of reviewers to detect a pattern, and most of the time, the people who notice them don't bring them up.

Also, there's a pattern that when we add rep incentives for moderation actions, things go badly. The +2 for editing while under 2k? You have no idea how many people I've seen making hundreds of edits to one tag or the same small spelling fix that get *hundreds* of reputation for it because no one detects the pattern.

Finally, obscure tags aren't a big enough problem to need this kind of system. What we have works well, and I think incentives will only make it worse.

Comment: OK. I think I will post a new question proposing the elimination of this tag. Thanks!